# Getting string length in winapi with strlen

Tags: c++, c, winapi, visual-c++, sendmessage

I'm trying to get length of buffer but i get Unhandled exception error.
can anyone help me please. What am I doing wrong?

```
case WM_COMMAND:
    switch (LOWORD(wp))
{
    case IDC_MAIN_BUTTON:
    {
        char buffer[256];

        SendMessage(hEdit,
            WM_GETTEXT,
            sizeof(buffer) / sizeof(buffer[0]),
            (LPARAM*)(buffer));
        int bl = strlen(buffer);
        MessageBox(NULL,
            bl,
            "Information",
            MB_ICONINFORMATION);
    }
        break;
}
```

Comment: `strlen` returns `size_t` type. Change `bl` to `size_t` type.

Comment: `SendMessage` also returns the text length.

Comment: My guess is that the call to `SendMessage` is failing and nothing is being written to `buffer`. Which means that it may not be null-terminated and the call to `strlen` will read beyond the end of the buffer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second parameter to [`MessageBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645505%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is a pointer to `TCHAR`. You pass an integer (and should have gotten a suitable warning at least).

You must first convert the integer to a string representation, for example in non-Unicode build:

```
    int bl = strlen(buffer);
    char buf[20];

    _snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "%d", bl);

    MessageBox(NULL, buf, "Information", MB_ICONINFORMATION);
```

(Caveat: Code not tested.)

Answer (score 0):

Besides [the mistake mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28009090/694576) by [*M Oehm*](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2979617/m-oehm) there are two more issues here:

1. The outcome of `SendMessage()` is not tested.
2. The buffer passed is uninitialised and is passed to `strlen()` in any case, so if not being set to a C-"string", that is contains as least one `'\0'` to serve as a `0`-terminator, the call to `strlen()` will fail.

To fix this at least change this:

```
char buffer[256];
```

to become

```
char buffer[256] = "";
```